# How to assign screenshots to picturebox without using too much RAM

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

So i have a code in which i create a bitmap and graphics and use CopyFromScreen method to take a screenshot, and then i proceed to assign it to the picturebox. It is inside a thread, so it keeps going. The problem is that the RAM consumption keeps going up, and if i try to use graphics.Dispose() and bitmap.Dispose(), it will give an error because pictureBox will not have anything to be displayed as the reference got deleted. I have already tried to clone the bitmap to another one and dispose the original, but the result is the same, the RAM still goes up.

This is more of a question that i got than a useful project, but the idea is that the picturebox gets a real-time copy of the whole screen.

How can i get around this?

Code sample:

```
while (run)
        {

            bitmap1 = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
            g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1);

            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, size);

            form.setPictureBox1(bitmap1);
            
            
            g.Dispose();
            bitmap1.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            

            Thread.Sleep(500);

        }
```

Comment: Think of this: I give you $50 to spend. You get to the shop, you place it on the counter. Before the cashier takes it, I snatch it and set it on fire. Can you still spend that $50? No. You're doing the same thing here. You're disposing of the image as soon as you've given it to the picturebox (note that you're not making a copy when you assign it to the picturebox - it's the same image). Wouldn't it make more sense to dispose of the old image?

Comment: Microsoft has a complete code example  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All native objects should be disposed. This includes graphics and bitmap objects. Your code fails because you still want to use the bitmap after you have taken the screenshot.

If you know you have a fixed size the simple method would be to only create the bitmap once, and reuse it for each screenshot:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(1920, 1080); // Make sure bitmap is disposed when the form is disposed.
public MyForm()
{
    myPictureBox.Image = myBitmap;
    ...
}
public void TakeScreenshot()
{
    using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
    {
          g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, myBitmap.Size);
    }
    myPictureBox.Invalidate();
 }
```

Another alternative would be to check if the picturebox already have an image, and dispose it before replacing it.

Comment: I got it now, thanks a lot! The main problem was that i was creating a lot of bitmaps, when i wrote the code that made sense in my head somehow, lol.

Answer (score 1):

As John suggested, you should dispose of the old image before creating a new one.  You can also dispose of the Graphics as well.

Here's a quick example showing one way this could be done:

```
private bool run = true;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread T = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Foo));
    T.IsBackground = true;
    T.Start();
}

private void Foo()
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    Size size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
    while (run)
    {
        bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        if (bmp != null)
        {
            bmp.Dispose();
        }

        bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, size);
        }                 
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't the operations in `Foo()` complain about cross-thread operations? Fairly sure you need to invoke that.

Comment: @Nyerguds, try it and tell me your results.  I'm fairly sure you'll be surprised...

Comment: @Idle_Mind That's hardly an answer to my question. It is never a good idea to assume everything is running correctly just because a single test run gave no errors. Try _not_ disposing that `bmp`, and running it for a couple of minutes. It'll probably keep working. Doesn't mean there's nothing going wrong.